# Convert a html string into a java "out.println"-statement

Tags: java, html, string, servlets, split

How can i convert a html string into a java "out.println" statement (with java)?

e.g.

```
<h1>Hello world</h1><p style="background-color:red">hello</p>
```

into

```
out.println("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
out.println("<p style=\"background-color:red\">hello</p>");
```

Comment: Are you looking for a HTML parser ?

Comment: Didn't you already answer your own question? What you posted works.

Comment: He maybe wants to automate this.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. I'm looking for a simple solution java solution which allows me to transform the html string into the "out.println("...")" output.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what do you really want to do ? Because if you want to generate a web page, using `println()` isn't the right tool.

Comment: have to do it that way i'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to ease editing, there is an option for this in Eclipse. Look in: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing -> In string literals -> Escape text when pasting into a string literal.

If you are trying to do this programmatically, this will suffice:

```
public static String escapeForQuotes(String s) {
    return escapeForQuotes(s, '\uFFFF');
}

public static String escapeForQuotes(String s, char ignore) {
    int len = s.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 6 / 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == ignore) { sb.append(c); continue; }
        switch (c) {
        case '\\': case '\"': case '\'': break;
        case '\n': c = 'n'; break;
        case '\r': c = 'r'; break;
        case '\0': c = '0'; break;
        default: sb.append(c); continue;
        }
        sb.append('\\').append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The function returns its input with backslashes inserted before quotes, backslashes, line breaks and nulls. The optional 'ignore' parameter allows you to specify one character that need not be escaped. E.g., `'` could be but need not be escaped in a `"`-quoted string, and vice-versa.

E.g.,

```
System.out.println("System.out.println(\"" + escapeForQuotes(html, '\'') + "\");");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below mentioned links

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)

 [Html Parser Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Regex replace. I take it you want to do the replace in your IDE. (Doing it in Java would need backslashes escaped, typically like `"\w"` becoming `"\\w"`.)

Replace

```
<(\w+)[^>]*>([.\r\n]*)</\1>
```

by

```
out.println("$2");\r\n
```

The `\1` matching the first group (the tag name).